# How to implement Login with Google in a Nativescript iOS app?

Tags: ios, angular, typescript, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm trying to implement google's id provider login in Nativescript through the nativescript-social-login plugin, so far it works well in Android, but it doesn't work at all in iOS.

Following the plugin creator's instructions i have noticed that some classes needed additional definition files for typescript, so researching the issue i came across the notion that the approach to achieve login with google has changed recently in iOS, and some pods have been deprecated. I've tried to follow the new method, i have defined by myself a d.ts file for the GIDSignIn delegate like this

```
declare class GIDSignIn{
   public static sharedInstance(): GIDSignIn;
   public handleURLSourceApplication(url: NSURL, sourceApplication:NSString, annotiation: id): boolean;
}
```

But even if this way the application compiles, it crashes as soon as i tap the login button.

By checking the build in xcode i get a warning that states that the Firebase instace has not been configured, how should i go about configuring it in the Typescript code

Comment: Can you share a minimal sample project where the issue can be reproduced? Between there are other plugins like [nativescript-plugin-firebase](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/) or [nativescript-oauth2](https://github.com/alexziskind1/nativescript-oauth2) which also implements Google SignIn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nativescript-oauth plugin for login with social.

> Example

**login.component.ts:-**

```
`import * as tnsOAuthModule from 'nativescript-oauth';

public login() {

    tnsOAuthModule.login()

        .then(() => {

            let tokenModule = JSON.stringify(tnsOAuthModule);

            let refereshToken = JSON.parse(tokenModule).instance.tokenResult.refreshToken;

            this.getRefereshActiveToken(refereshToken);
        })

        .catch((er) => {

            console.error('error logging in');

            console.dir(er);

        });

}`
```

> Add google authentication configuration in main.ts file Like.

```
`import * as tnsOAuthModule from 'nativescript-oauth';

var myInitOptions: tnsOAuthModule.ITnsOAuthCredentials = {

authority: '',

authorizeEndpoint: '',

tokenEndpoint: '',

clientId: '',

redirectUri: 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob',

responseType: "code",

scope: 'openid',

};

tnsOAuthModule.initCustom({

credentials: myInitOptions,

cookieDomains: ['http://demoweb.net'],

});`
```

**For IOS only add this code for redirection after successfully authenticate on google in App_Resources -> iOS -> info.plist file.**

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>

<array>

    <dict>

        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>

        <string>Editor</string>

        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>

        <string>app_id</string>

        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>

        <array>

            <string>appauth</string>

        </array>

    </dict>

</array>

<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>

<dict>

    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>

    <true/>

</dict>
```